# How to open new page into my website using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mysql, jsp

***I'll try my best to explain what i'm looking for.***

Have a look, into this [image]

I've a lot's of news into my website. and i'm showing all that news using `select * from table_name` using MySql database.

You know, showing all much news into one page looks so buggy. Now I've planned that i would show only titles(means using `h1` tag) into my one web page but if clients click on that title. It must suppose to redirect with full news of web page of that title. Is it possible? I guess so.. Because `sciencealert.com` do the same thing.

Can you please help me?

***Surely, Help would be appreciated!!***

**EDITED:**

Some peoples are suggesting me to use `anchor tag`. But I put my news into database. Then how is it possible to redirect on particular Webpage? Any tricks?

Comment: how you search the internet or tried something?

Comment: is your's a blog kinda website ? if it is so you can go with wordpress

Comment: @raja beta: It looks like you have some basic problems about web programing... Website structure organization has nothing to do with database/mySQL. I would advise you to find a professional for this task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
<a href="detail.jsp?newsID=id">
<h1>news title</h1>
</a>
```

in `detail.jsp` page write code to retrieve new with specified id that is `newsID`

write sql query - `select * from news where newsid = id`

display all data on that page

Comment: Yes, This is what i'm looking for.. Can you show me the best tutorial link for it?

Comment: Please at least could you tell me, What do we say this logical process? any name for it?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97336_01/buslog.102/a83726/basics7.htm @rajabeta

Answer (score 0):

Use anchor tags `<a>` with `target="_blank"`:

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mzLn4gqd/)

Comment: No, This is not that thing what i'm looking for.. I put my news into Database. So how should i suppose to show anchor tag with my particular news..

Comment: @rajabeta You need to add anchor tags to the page where you have all the titles. One anchor tag for each title.

Comment: Okay, Here you could see what i'm looking for .. http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/1399/how-to-pass-data-from-one-page-to-another-page-using-querystring

Comment: @rajabeta Follow those instructions in that article. Add an appropriate URL that points to your news article in the `href` part of anchor tag.